# How to stop multiple terminals to sync with one-another?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I've got an Oh-my-zsh terminal with the spaceship theme (this might not be the proper name) and all the terminal tabs and windows are syncing constantly (running Ubuntu 20.04).

Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: What do you mean by "synching constantly"?

Comment: It's like I'm typing in all at the same time they are basically the same, while I just try to use one.

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Does `echo $$` show different results?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and no it's literally the same when I type it seem like I type in all of them, everything is the same. So it's no just syncing the output it's syncing everything